# How should questions in the Reopen Votes queue be handled when they are completely different from the original question?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-reopen

An example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/4302416).

If a question that is on hold appears in the RV queue because it's edited, and the question now asks something completely different, how should these be handled?

Shadow Wizard [suggested](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1884856#1884856) that such questions can be reopened when they have no answer yet. I followed this advice and voted *Leave Closed*.

It seems the question was reopened after all, what should be done now? Should the edit be reverted and the question closed again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shadow Wizard is right. If a closed question has no answers, then completely changing it to a different question that fits the rules of the site does no harm, so it can be reopened. That's not the case here though, so that question should have been improved, not completely replaced with a new question. I've rolled back the edit, closed the question, and left a comment.